# Need to get server bandwidth usage up to the moment (in bytes)

Tags: unix, shell, bandwidth

I am writing a CRON/PHP script that will check the server stats every 5 minutes (CPU/RAM/SSD) and log the info to the database. This way I will be able to see server usage over different periods of time.

I am curious also to see how much bandwidth is used at what time in a day. I'd like to have a counter which would always increase. Then I could read the file every 5 minutes and calculate the difference.

The alternative solution I am using now is:

```
bwm-ng -o plain -u bytes -T sum -c 1 -t $(( 1000 * 5 * 60 ))
```

However, the problem with the latter is that it takes 5 minutes to return the result. Therefore, can anyone suggest how to approach the issue with the file that stores data usage all the time?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. There are tons of utilities available that do what you want to do. Have a look at Munin, Cacti, Nagios, mrtg, just to name a few.

Comment: I don't want anything heavy, just simple script. Munin and others therefore don't seem like a solution.

Comment: Munin is not heavy at all, the time you take to develop, debug and tweak your script would definitely be better used learning how to set up Munin.

Comment: Have you looked at rrdtool? you can configure it to do what you want and build nice pretty graphics tto display in a web page. No need to install a database server for this either.  It's all built in.

Comment: Munin uses rrdtool in the background, IMHO trying to learn how to use rrdtool "raw" is just as much reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way imho is to use `iptables`.

Add a line to the top of your `iptables` that matches everything, and then just cut the output of `iptables -L -v -n` and then `iptables -Z` to zero the counters.

Its quick and dirty, but it'll likely work for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line, you have quite a few tools that can do the job. If you're not interested in the established [Orca](http://www.orcaware.com), [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), and [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) tools, look at [nmon from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/). This can be run interactively, but also outputs data to: `/var/log/nmon`. That's an option.

Comment: It looks like the last time nmon was updated was back in 2006?

Answer (score 1):

Munin isn't particular heavyweight, but anyway: The most basic command to get your info is just plain `ifconfig`.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:x.x.x.x  Bcast:x.x.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:108930219 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12486564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2734738082 (2.7 GB)  TX bytes:2665032097 (2.6 GB)
          Interrupt:11 Base address:0x8000
```

See the line with `RX bytes`? Use a

With `netstat -s` or `/proc/net/netstat`, you can drill down a lot more down to specific protocols.

Comment: bear in mind that loops at 4gb.

Comment: Yep, but avoiding that pitfall should be straightforward (and Munin etc. already do that ...).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty demo using iptables. You should be ablr to figure out for yourself how to modify this for your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -I INPUT
iptables -I OUTPUT
iptables -Z
while true
do
    iptables -L -Z  INPUT  -v -n | awk 'NR==3 { print "INPUT bytes " $2 }'
    iptables -L -Z  OUTPUT  -v -n | awk 'NR==3 { print "OUTPUT Bytes " $2 }'
    sleep 20
done
```

which gives

```
INPUT bytes 0
OUTPUT Bytes 108
INPUT bytes 270K
OUTPUT Bytes 1777K
INPUT bytes 1760K
OUTPUT Bytes 12M
INPUT bytes 40
OUTPUT Bytes 216
```

Note that each time this is run a new blank rule is added to the INPUT and OUTPUT chain which is not a good thing.